# Keeping original hyphen-minus character with the sourcesanspro package

Tags: xetex, punctuation, sourcesanspro

The [sourcesanspro package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/sourcesanspro/), which loads the Source Sans Pro font, changes the hyphen characters. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\begin{document}
Hello-world.
\end{document}
```

This produces the following text in the PDF when compiled with XeLaTeX:

```
Hello‑world.
```

Notice the narrower hyphen character: instead of the [hyphen-minus character (U+002D)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002D) in the source, it is a [hyphen character (U+2010)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2010).

If the `sourcesanspro` package is not used, the output PDF contains the hyphen-minus (U+002D) character.

With PDFLaTeX, the problem does not occur.

How can I keep the hyphen-minus character when using the `sourcesanspro` package?

Comment: I believe it's a feature of SourceSansPro.